# Read HTML Function Failed to Crawl Pokemongo Data Tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to practice using the read_html function from pandas by crawling a table but I got an error. My code as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.pokemondb.net/pokedex/all"
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
```

The above code returned errors and didn't work out, so I tried the one following, but it still doesn't work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = "https://www.pokemondb.net/pokedex/all"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
dfs = pd.read_html(soup.table)
```

I don't exactly know what's wrong. Can anyone enlighten me on that?

Thanks!

Comment: what error ? Always put full error message in question (as text, not image). Don't expect that we will run code to see your error. And code can run without error on our computers.

Comment: I have no problem with `pd.read_html(html.text)` without `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation for [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) you can read that it doesn't work with `https`

So your first version confirms this.

---

In second version you don't need `BeautifulSoup`.

`read_html()` uses own `bs4` or `lxml` or `html5` - see in documentation option `flavor` to select it.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.pokemondb.net/pokedex/all"
html = requests.get(url)

dfs = pd.read_html(html.text)

print(dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may help you.

```
table = soup.findAll('table', attrs={'id':'pokedex'})
```

then convert table as string.

```
 dfs = pd.read_table(str(table))
```

It will give you an output.